# Get a Name from a GameObject that touches another one (2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im wondering how I can get the Name from a `GameObject` that is touching my `GameObject` with my attached script.

I tried it with colliders but it won't seem to work for me.

This is the object where my script is on.

[image: Image 1]

And now I want to get the Name from this `GameObject` below.

[image: Image 2]

How is this possible?

Comment: Welcome new user !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's actually just ".name" !

So something like ...

```
protected void OnCollisionEnter(Collision info) {

    string theName = info.transform.name;
    Debug.Log("the name is " + theName);
```

Depending on your game, it's possible you'll have to understand how to use triggers (basically set the colliders to be triggers), but really that's a whole other issue.

It's also quite common to use "tags".  (Just set them in the Inspector.)

```
protected void OnCollisionEnter(Collision info) {

    if (!info.transform.CompareTag("trees")) {

        Debug.Log("we just hit a tree, do nothing");
        return;
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Do I need to add a Rigidbody2D and a Collider2D to the GameObjects?

Comment: Both objects need a `Collider2D` yes. A non-kinematic `Rigidbody2D`  must be on at least one of the colliding objects. So, only one of them can be without a `Rigidbody2D`.

Comment: hi @TheUnknownDev - don't hesitate to ask a NEW question if you have more questions.  And don't forget to search as there are many questions about it already, also!

Comment: I'm so pleased, @TheUnknownDev !!

Comment: Now it wont work again :( Here some Images how I used the Collider and Rigidbody [link](https://imgur.com/a/nYkMm8J) [link](https://imgur.com/a/uQ1i8gI) [link](https://imgur.com/a/0bfVyoG)

Comment: i gotta feeing you need to ask a new question, unfortunately!!!  folks will rush to answer it.  "My colliders are not colliding ..."